# Ubuntu server 12.04 use apt-get to update but error

Tags: apt

```
Unpacking linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic (from .../linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic_3.2.0-40.64_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal bzip2 read error: 'DATA_ERROR'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic_3.2.0-40.64_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 short read on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./lib/modules/3.2.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nouveau.ko'
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-40-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-40-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic_3.2.0-40.64_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

I use `apt-get clean` 4~6 times, but still fails in system update.

Does anyone help me to pass this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bizip exit code 2 means corrupted file .

man bzip2

.... to indicate a corrupt com‐pressed file, 3 ... ( line 76 )

i suggest you to check another source

direct download : http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic_3.2.0-40.64_amd64.deb